# mysql update of a field and consequent usage of it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pure theoretical question, with a nonsense example:

```
  UPDATE mytable
      binaryData = '___GIANT_BINARY_DATA___',
      isBig      = LENGTH('___THE_SAME_GIANT_BINARY_DATA___') > 1000000000
  WHERE id = 22
```

Now, if my binary data is a "gillion bytes", i want to avoid to write it twice in the plain SQL

```
  UPDATE mytable
      binaryData = '___GIANT_BINARY_DATA___',
      isBig      = LENGTH(binaryData) > 1000000000
  WHERE id = 22
```

**I want to update a column field, then re-use it, using its column name, in the same query**

or maybe is there a way to define an alias in the UPDATE syntax, like i can do with SELECT?

thank you in advance

(p.s. i'm also interested in to the equivalent INSERT syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql is an oddity in that the `SET` statements are non-atomic, meaning that as soon as one column is assigned a new value, that new value will be reflected if it is used elsewhere in the update statement.

The following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE Swap (
  a CHAR(1),
  b CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO Swap (a, b) VALUES ('a', 'b');

UPDATE Swap SET a = b, b = a;

SELECT * FROM Swap;
```

Will result in `b`, `b` in MySql, but `b`, `a` in every other RBDMS that I'm aware of...

So for your question, you don't need to alias `binaryData`, because soon as it is updated, the updated value will be reflected in the `isBig` assignment statement.

However, it's probably a bad idea to rely on this behavior, since it is non-standard.

Comment: Doesn't help with INSERT though.

Comment: @JustinSwanhart True... I think the insert could be handled with either your suggestion or something similar to Zane's.  I didn't comment on it because you guys already covered it pretty well...

Comment: what about the insert syntax INSERT INTO table SET a = 2, b = a ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE     mytable a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT '__GIANT_BINARY_DATA__' AS bindata) b
SET        a.binaryDate = b.bindata,
           a.isBig = LENGTH(b.bindata) > 1000000000
WHERE      a.id = 22
```

Which will give you access to that same value in every row, and you only have to pass in the data once in the SQL statement string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user variable:

```
set @content = '___GIANT_BINARY_DATA___';
UPDATE mytable
   SET binaryData = @content,
       isBig = LENGTH(@content) > 1000000000
 WHERE id = 22;
set @content = NULL; -- free up memory
```